# Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got identifier "rfm" at [23:1]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Looking for support to fix this. I'm getting the error as below
**Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got identifier "rfm" at [23:1]**

```
with combinedtable as (
-- get user id, purchase Delivery_Date and purchase Subtotal from main data table
    select 
        maintable.Customer_id, 
        maintable.Delivery_Date, 
        recentDelivery_Date.recent_Delivery_Date, 
        sum(maintable.Subtotal) as Subtotal,
        count(maintable.Customer_id) as totalevents 
    from `piattosteakhouse.ALFACO.Ordering_Co_Orders` as maintable
    -- replace <your table> with your data table.
    -- get the Delivery_Date of last purchase for each user and join it with maintable to get the last purchase CDelivery_Date
    join 
    (
        SELECT 
            Customer_id, 
            max(Delivery_Date) as recent_CDelivery_Date 
        from maintable 
        group by 1
    ) as recentCDelivery_Date
    on maintable.Customer_id = recentCDelivery_Date.Customer_id
    group by 1,2,3
)
rfm as (
  select 
    Customer_id, 
    Delivery_Date_DIFF(current_CDelivery_Date(),recent_CDelivery_Date,day) as recency, 
    count(Customer_id) as frequency, 
    sum(Subtotal) as monetary  
  from combinedtable
  group by 1,2
  order by recency
)

-- show final table.
select * from rfm
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: `), rfm` maybe (note the comma)?

Comment: When i add the , (Getting this error: Table name "maintable" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request

Comment: `with recursive` ?